# SSRS - columns of charts

Tags: reporting-services

I need to add a chart for each group to a report.

If I create a table and add a chart so each group is created automatically, there is one chart per line which wastes a lot of real estate (the rest of the report is landscape).

Is there a way (other than creating each chart separately) to have multiple charts per row of a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a burst of inspiration and was able to create a 5 x 3 matrix of charts using a matrix. Thought I'd share in case anyone else had a similar need.

I joined my original query to a derived table that had each group name and used Row_Number() over the group name to add sequential numbers.

For the matrix column grouping I used:

```
=Fields!ROW_NUM.Value MOD 5
```

And for the Row Grouping:

```
=INT((Fields!ROW_NUM.Value - 1) / 5)
```

Bam! Five columns of charts. Simply change the 5 to whatever number of columns desired. The same method could be used to put a single data element in multiple columns of a report. Not something anyone would do normally but may come in handy.